# HTTPS certificate issue for postman for dotnet webapi project [version dotnet 5.0]. How can it be solved?

Tags: ssl, https, postman

The problem is showing after requesting by following command on terminal.

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

*Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. **Trusting the certificate on Linux distributions automatically is not supported.** For instructions on how to manually trust the certificate on your Linux distribution, go to https://aka.ms/dev-certs-trust*

A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.

[image]

Thanks for watching and helping me in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Change Settings:

1. General Settings

---

Postman tries to minimize the number of settings you have to change, so some defaults are automatically set. You can customize your settings based on your use case.

2. Request

---

**SSL certificate verification** (native apps only): Prevents Postman from checking validity of SSL certificates while making a request. Set this option to OFF to open requests in a new tab. This option is, by default, set to OFF.

[image: Image of Postman settings.]

For more information please visit [Troubleshooting requests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/troubleshooting-api-requests/) or [Setting up Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/settings/)

Answer (score 2):

**ECONNREFUSED is not certificate error it means the port is not open , meaning nothing is running on 5001.**

Make sure your service is up and running and is accessible through localhost:5001

Comment: Yes sir. My service is up and running and is accessible. And found a solution for this problem. Thank you sir.

Comment: Yes sir you are right. May be I uploaded a wrong picture.